# Existence of Solution of Linear ODE on Whole Real Line

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let 
$$ \dot{x} = Ax + d, \quad x(0) = c$$

be a linear $n$-dimensional system of ordinary differential equations with $A$ being a (constant) $n \times n$- coefficient matrix and $c,d$ being (constant) $n$-dimensional vectors.

Due to Picard-Lindelöff, we know, that this initial value problem has a unique solution in a small interval $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$.

Can we push this even further and claim that the above problem always has a unique solution function, which is defined on the whole real line $\mathbb{R}$ ? If yes, why?

Comment: Your suspicion is true and the unique solution is $x(t) = e^{tA}\left(c + \int_0^te^{-sA}d\,ds\right)$.